# Delete Access Request from certain date and backwards

Tags: 2013, access

We have the following code to delete all access requests b/c we are controlling permissions via AD Groups.

What we'd like to do is delete access requests from a certain date and later because that would give us a point in time where we though we had permission groups setup properly, but maybe something was missed.

Code so far is as followings, but we'd like to put a date clause to keep more recent requests to analyse what was missed:

```
<script src=" http://spsite.com/sites/assets/include/scripts/1.11.1/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$("#btnClickDeleteAccessRequests").click(deleteFunction);

function deleteFunction() {

 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){


   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
   list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Access Requests'),
   query = new SP.CamlQuery(),
   items = list.getItems(query);
ctx.load(items, "Include(Id)");
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    var enumerator = items.getEnumerator(),
        simpleArray = [];
    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        simpleArray.push(enumerator.get_current());
    }
    for (var s in simpleArray) {
        simpleArray[s].deleteObject();
    }
    ctx.executeQueryAsync();
});   

}, "sp.js");
}});
</script>
<input type="button" id="btnClickDeleteAccessRequests" value="Click Here" />
```

Comment: i would suggest you post it as an answer and mark it..

Answer (score 0):

08.08.2016 Update >> got the code to work as follows with date range:

```
<script src="/sites/assets/include/scripts/1.11.1/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Documents/styleDatePicker.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$("#btnClickDeleteAccessRequests").click(deleteFunction);

function deleteFunction() {

 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){


   var query;
var startDate = $("#fromdatepicker").datepicker("getDate");
var endDate = $("#todatepicker").datepicker("getDate");
if(startDate==null){
alert('Please select Start Date.');
return;
}
if(endDate==null){
alert('Please select End Date.');
return;
}
if(startDate !=null && endDate !=null){
startDate  =  startDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(startDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+startDate.getDate()+'T00:00:01Z'; 
endDate  =  endDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(endDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+endDate.getDate()+'T00:00:01Z'; 

query = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>"+startDate+ "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>"+ endDate + "</Value></Leq></And></Where></Query></View>";
}
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Access Requests');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);
items = list.getItems(camlQuery);

ctx.load(items, "Include(Id)");
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    var enumerator = items.getEnumerator(),
        simpleArray = [];
    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        simpleArray.push(enumerator.get_current());
    }
    for (var s in simpleArray) {
        simpleArray[s].deleteObject();
    }
    ctx.executeQueryAsync();
});   

}, "sp.js");
}});


  $( function() {
    $( "#fromdatepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );

$( function() {
    $( "#todatepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );

</script>

<table width="300px">
<tr>
<td>Start Date:</td><td><input type="text" id="fromdatepicker"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>End Date:</td><td><input type="text" id="todatepicker"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="button" id="btnClickDeleteAccessRequests" value="Delete Date Range Access Requests" />
```